# xmodmap periodic resets on Xubuntu

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xmodmap

I'm running Xubuntu 11.04 and i'm using a KeyOvation mac compatible Gold Touch keyboard. Because the weird ordering of ctrl, option, and the apple key, I wanted to remap the keys to my liking using xmodmap. Here's the settings file I'm using.

```
remove mod4 = Super_L
remove mod4 = Super_R
remove control = Control_L
remove control = Control_R
remove mod1 = Alt_L
remove mod1 = Alt_R
keysym Control_L = Super_L
keysym Control_R = Super_R
keysym Super_L = Alt_L
keysym Super_R = Alt_R
keysym Alt_L = Control_L
keysym Alt_R = Control_R
add control = Control_L
add control = Control_R
add mod4 = Super_L
add mod4 = Super_R
add mod1 = Alt_L
add mod1 = Alt_R
```

It works great when I call xmodmap on it. However, after a few minutes, the settings will no longer work and revert to the default settings and I have to call xmodmap again to get it to work. What could be the causes for this?

I've tried looking around a bit for this problem with little success. [One guy](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=286934) claimed that he got around this by removing scim and I prefer not to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: does this AU Question help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/1142/how-can-i-stop-gnome-screensaver-from-resetting-my-keyboard-to-its-default-layo

Comment: Not the same issue. The bindings just periodically reset regardless of what i'm doing

Comment: It may help if you go to the xfce Settings manager, Sessions and Startup and disable 'launch Gnome services on startup' at the 'Advanced' tab.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem (although using Xubuntu 12.04).
What helped in my case was removing the keyboard-layout switch applet from my panel.
Somehow this applet periodically sets the keyboard layout thus overriding anything that is set via xmodmap.